# How to center-align a left-aligned list in Bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm very much an HTML/CSS beginner, so I'm having trouble with the following: The list items (with icons) in this Bootstrap modal are correctly left-aligned in relation to one another. However, I want the entire list to appear in the center of the modal.

To get the list items to left-align properly, I have this in my CSS:

```
.modal-list > li > a {
  color:#333;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

And here's (what I think is) the relevant HTML:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign up or log in using OpenID</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        At this time, CloudSim is in beta and by invitation only. If you have received an invite, pick a login option below.
        <!--OpenID options -->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu-modal" style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li>
              <a href="/auth/google"><img class="inline-block"
                 alt="Google" width="46" src="/img/icons/google.svg"/> Google</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/auth/yahoo"><img class="inline-block"
                 alt="Yahoo" width="46" src="/img/icons/yahoo.svg"> Yahoo</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/auth/aol"><img class="inline-block"
                 alt="AOL" width="46" src="/img/icons/aol.svg"> AOL</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/auth/openid"><img class="inline-block"
                 alt="OpenId" width="46" src="/img/icons/openid.svg"> OpenId</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <!-- end here -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of modal -->
```

I don't have sufficient "reputation" to post an image, so here's a link to how it looks currently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t9CA.jpg

Comment: can you add your html also

Comment: Added! Let me know if there's something missing :)

Comment: can try adding a specific width to the ul and use margin auto like this `.dropdown-menu-modal{width:100px;margin:0 auto;}`

Comment: Oh, that does work, thanks! Do you think this will mess up the responsiveness of the layout on a smaller device?

Comment: since the width is just 100px, i don't think it will mess up in smaller devices

Answer (score 0):

You can give the a a width of 100% and then align the text to the center.

That would be responsive, so you wouldn't need to worry about adding specific widths.

Try adding these two lines of CSS

```
.modal-list > li > a {
  color:#333;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;

  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One unfortunate side effect of this approach is that the images/icons are then no longer left-aligned. Since the AOL login option is shorter than the others, it looks a bit funky. Not sure if there is a way to left-align the li items...

Comment: I'd need to have a look, but there's probably a solution. Do you have a live version, or an updated screenshot I can see?